# Crystal .cycle Recycle after finish looping

Tags: loops, crystal-lang

so in my case

```
def dynamic_data()
  data = [] of String
  # some data from db
  # data << db["somekey"].to_s
  return data
end

dynamic_data().cycle do |d|
  # some stuff
  puts d
end
```

My data reaches more than 500 row and will continue to grow and increase, how to make cycle finishing loop first, then reload new data again from function, or there is other method ? , thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how to make `cycle` finishing loop first

There is no way to make [`Array#cycle`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-cycle) finishing, since it is explicitly designed to run forever (unless `break` is called, but this is unlikely what you are looking for).

If I properly understood your intent, you are trying to handle incoming portions of data. To do so, one needs more sophisticated handling, like:

```
class DataHandler
  def initialize
    @data = []
  end
  def data()
    @data.tap(&:clear)
  end
  def data!(new_data)
    @data << new_data
  end
end

data_handler = DataHandler.new

loop do
  break "empty data" if data_handler.data.empty?
  puts data_handler.data
end
```

---

Or, as pointed out in comments by Jonne Haß, using `yield`:

```
def dynamic_data()
  data = []
  loop do
    data << new_data
    yield data.tap(&:clear) if data.size > 100
  end
end

dynamic_data do
  puts d
end
```

Comment: `since it is explicitly designed to run forever` ,, finish your job first (looping), then recycle again, that was i mean

Comment: A more idiomatic way would be to put the loop into the data fetching method and let it initiate a callback for every block of data using `yield`.

Comment: @JonneHaß to freeze data fetching if `yield` takes too long? Sounds like you have never dealt with back pressure.

Comment: If that's an issue and the processing function is concurrency safe you can just wrap the callback into `spawn`.

Comment: @JonneHaß that is true. Honestly, ruby just sucks on such tasks. I personally prefer to follow SRP, but yes, I would agree `yield` would be more idiomatic way to go (though not the best one IMHO.)

Comment: @JonneHaß I have updated the answer with `yield` as you’ve suggested, thanks.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/xDGUPTtQ my current dynamic function @mudasobwa , btw &:clear `expected a function type, not Symbol` in crystal @JonneHaß , thanks for your question, i'll try it

Comment: Is this answer for Ruby or Crystal? tagged as crystal-lang but code looks like Ruby (no array type mandatory in Crystal)